# Kendo grid: destroy functionality not working

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid where I display list of documents uploaded by user. In the grid I have a button called "Delete" which triggers the dataSource function "destroy" which calls the delete service class. To achieve the deletion of document I am passing the documentId which was selected by user into a query to the service class by doing the following in my datasource:

```
   destroy: {
                        url: function (options) {
                            options.IsActive = false;
                          // type: "POST";                             
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf8";
                            return constants.serviceUrl + "Document/Delete?id=" + options.DocumentId;
                        },
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json"
                },
```

For some reason along with documentId it is adding all the data associated with this document which is not what I intend to do.Here is what the URL looks like in fiddler.

```
http://localhost/Services/HumanResources/api/Document/Delete?id=2&DocumentId=2&ReviewId=0&DocumentTypeId=2&Name=Applications+to+Install.docx&DocumentData=UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQCUZeTvkgEAAK4HAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbCCiBAIooAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAe&CreatedById=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&CreatedDate=0001-01-01T00%3A00%3A00&RawFileName=&DocumentTypeName=Manager
```

I have set breakpoint to my  destroy function and made sure that documentID just have a number nothing else. Because of this long URL which is wrong the service class is never getting hit. Below is what fiddler says:

```
> HTTP/1.1 414 Request-URI Too Long
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Wed, 09 Dec 2015 15:00:46 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 329

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Request URL Too Long</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Request URL Too Long</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Any idea what my destroy function is adding all the extra data which I am not even passing to the service URL link ?

Answer (score 0):

I think kendo dataSouce by default is adding whole model to every ajax method. You can write your own parameter map funtion like in this example: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.destroy

But you need to check if read/update/create functions keep gets the correct data.

So add to your dataSource parameterMap returning empty object for destroy request type and just pass model property for others:

```
parameterMap: function(data, type) {
  if (type === "destroy") {
    return {  };
  }
  else {
       return { models: kendo.stringify(data.models) };
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Jaroslaw. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I am not sure why the destroy call was adding the whole model to ajax call. but doing the above fixed my problem. I am not clear as to what does return { } do under type ==="destroy"

Comment: Ouch, return {} overrides default kendo returning-whole-model behavior and mean return empty object. You can also change your destroy url function by removing DocumentId from there and return here: `return { id: options.DocumentId };` And you probably still want to `read`, `update` and `create` works the same way so you must just return nothing for destroy type. (=== is the same what == but it compares type of data also and it good habbit to use === instead ==).